# NGRX 11 throwing error when is installed in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, version, ngrx

I'm facing an issue cause this error :

```
ERROR in node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/reducer_creator.d.ts:32:99 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

32 export declare function on<State, Creators extends readonly ActionCreator[]>(...args: [...creators: Creators, reducer: OnReducer<State, Creators>]): ReducerTypes<State, Creators>;
                                                                                                     ~
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/reducer_creator.d.ts:32:118 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

32 export declare function on<State, Creators extends readonly ActionCreator[]>(...args: [...creators: Creators, reducer: OnReducer<State, Creators>]): ReducerTypes<State, Creators>;
```

According to what I have seen on the internet it , has to do with the typescript version?
I did try to set a lower version of type script , or a higher one, but still doesn't work.

My version of Angular is :

```
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 10.0.8
Node: 12.13.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.0.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/core              10.0.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.8
@angular/cdk                      10.2.7
@angular/cli                      10.0.8
@angular/material                 10.2.7
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.8
@schematics/angular               10.0.8
@schematics/update                0.1000.8
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        4.0.7
webpack                           4.43.0
```

And the package.json has this structure:

```
{
  "name": "bookmark",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.5",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^11.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.7"
  }
}
```

As I said I have deleted node-modules , several times and have set lower and higher typescript versions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@ngrx 11 requires Angular 11.
Try installing @ngrx 10.

```
"@ngrx/effects": "^10.1.2",
"@ngrx/store": "^10.1.2",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^10.1.2",
```